What is wrong with the following proof of the Adjoint Functor Theorem?
I'm reading about (versions of) the adjoint functor theorem and in particular looking at total categories.
As I understand it, there is a theorem which says if $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}$ are locally small categories and $\mathcal{C}$ is a total category then a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{D}$ admits a right adjoint iff it preserves colimits.
Now, I have tried to prove this myself: say $L$ is the right adjoint for the Yoneda embedding $Y:\mathcal{C}\to Pshv(\mathcal{C}),$ and $G^f:\mathcal{D}\to Pshv(\mathcal{C})$ the formal adjoint of $F$. Define $G=LG^f$.
Then we have a natural isomorphism $Hom_\mathcal{D}(x,Gy)\cong Hom_\mathcal{Fun}(Y(x),G^fy)$ due to the adjunction, but also a natural isomorphism $Hom_\mathcal{C}(Y(x),G^f(y))\cong G^f(y)(x)=Hom_\mathcal{C}(Fx,y)$ by the Yoneda Lemma.
Does this not imply $G$ is right adjoint to $F$?
Of course, something has to be wrong somewhere as this doesn't use that $F$ preserves colimits but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. The proof I have seen of this result I find a bit confusing (it's from my uni course): it uses colimits to describe what $L$ looks like, then says because $F$ preserves colimits you find a natural isomorphism like above, but then also goes on to define a unit and counit for the adjunction, which seems unnecessary if you have the natural isomorphism of Hom's so I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on this. Many thanks!

$\DeclareMathOperator{colim}{colim}$The Yoneda embedding almost never has a right adjoint as you're requiring. The correct definition of a total category is that its Yoneda embedding has a left adjoint.
For the Yoneda embedding to have a right adjoint, it must preserve all colimits. Colimits in presheaf categories are computed pointwise. That is, $(\colim_i F_i)(c) = \colim_i (F_i(c))$. So if $Y$ preserves colimits, that means that $Y(\colim_i c_i)(c) \cong (\colim_i Y(c_i))(c) = \colim_i (Y(c_i)(c))$. Expanding $Y$, that means that $\mathcal{C}(c, \colim_i c_i) \cong \colim_i \mathcal{C}(c, c_i)$, which is to say that $\mathcal{C}(c, -)$ preserves colimits for every $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$. This means that every object of $\mathcal{C}$ is tiny.
Now, it seems to be an open question whether any non-trivial categories have all objects tiny, but a comment on this question indicates that this is impossible for cocomplete categories. So in your situation, where $\mathcal{C}$ is total and thus cocomplete, we cannot have a right adjoint to the Yoneda embedding.

Of course I got my adjoints mixed up. Thanks for clarifying!
